# jQuery hasClass / addClass Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is what I have. The li has a class of current but for some reason it's not adding the class.

```
if (jQuery("#sidebar li").hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("booyah");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing if you even get the right element, and hasClass actually returns true?

Comment: I think, your problem is you don't understand `this` (I may be wrong)
`this` is only scoped inside of 
a) object method calls - to the object
b) event handlers - to the caller

@Julian's answer is the way to go, though there's even a simpler way (see my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The true and easy way: `jQuery("#sidebar li.current").addClass('booyah')`
(If I understood your question, and you want to add 'booyah' to the li element already having 'current')

Comment: That is the easy, I don't know why I was over complicating things. Thanks.

Comment: yep, jQuery is extremely powerful thanks to selectors and its permissive nature - the code won't fail if there's no 'current' li =)

Answer (score 6):

this pointer is not referencing the $("#sidebar li") element.

```
if (jQuery("#sidebar li").hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery("#sidebar li").addClass("booyah");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try var'ing the side bar el first. I don't think "this" is what you think it is.

```
var $sideBar = jQuery("#sidebar li");

if ($sideBar.hasClass("current")) {
       $sideBar.addClass("booyah");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `this` as you are not in a context where `this` represents `#sidebar li`.  Instead consolidate your jQuery selector to a variable and reuse the variable.  This provides efficiency, as you only need to search for the element in question once, instead of twice.

```
var sidebarli = jQuery("#sidebar li");
if (sidebarli.hasClass("current")) {
    sidebarli.addClass("booyah");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var $li = jQuery("#sidebar li");

if ($li.hasClass("current")) {
        $li.addClass("booyah");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/shaneburgess/STZUb/

```
$.each(jQuery("#sidebar li"),function(){
   if (jQuery(this).hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("current").addClass("booyah");
    }
});
```